# Check if a user with a specific role reacted the latest bot message | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

i need to make my bot check if someone with admin role or a specific role reacted the bot's latest message

i made a *suggestion command* for my bot and i want to the bot **check if anyone with the @Admin role reacted the latest bot message of #suggestions channel**, then when a user that has the @Admin role react the suggestion, make the bot send me a DM saying something like:  **Accepted your suggestion!**

Comment: Please see the docs for the event [messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) {
if(reaction.message.channel.id !== 'suggestion channel id') return;
let channel = reaction.message.channel;
let msg = await channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1});
if(!msg || msg.id !== reaction.message.id) return;
if(reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.some(r => r.id === 'admin role id')) {
user.send('Your suggestion was accepted.')
//You may have said this wrong, but if you want the person who suggested it to be DMd
//You will need to somehow save their name (or id which can never change), let’s say you put it in the footer of an embed for the suggestion
let userID = reaction.message.embeds[0].footer;
msg.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.user.id === userID).send('Accepted your suggestion!')
}
})
```

I’d like to know if this doesn’t work because I didn’t get to test it. It may have some errors, but hopefully not

Comment: When I implement this, I get the error, "reaction.message.guild.member is not a function"